# Java framework recommendation for asp.net mvc developer

Tags: c#, java, asp.net-mvc, hibernate, model-view-controller

I'm a C# ASP.net MVC Developer.

I got a new job and have to move to the java world (which I left few years ago :))

Are there any recommendations for 
asp.net mvc equivalent java framework

also, 
are there any simmilar technologies like LINQ in java world?
(I've used LINQ with entity framework, I guess I would use Hibernate with it's own query language)

Also, is there a good book / tutorial you know for C# to Java transition?

update: I'm currenly looking at Spring MVC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend looking at Spring.  It's like Enterprise Framework on the .NET side, if I understand the latter correctly.

It's a library of modules built on top of dependency injection and aspect oriented programming.

Comment: After evaluation, I think Spring MVC suits me best

Answer (score 4):

Check [Play framework](http://www.playframework.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Apache Struts is an equivalent to ASP.NET MVC:

http://struts.apache.org/

Answer (score 1):

I used Struts 2 and no problem.

http://struts.apache.org/2.x/index.html

Note: I do NOT recommend Struts 1. They are completely different. Struts 2 is way better.

Disclaimer: I use Ruby on Rails now :)

Edit:

The official docs has plenty of documentation.
http://struts.apache.org/2.2.1.1/docs/home.html

Comment: thank you for the answer. Currently I'm reading a small free book about struts 2 I found on infoq.com

Comment: @Emir: Vote up if you find an answer useful. Can you tell me the name of the book and/or link?  I can add it to my answer.

Comment: I've read a book found on http://www.infoq.com/minibooks/starting-struts2. I didn't quite liked the book. If you have any recommendiations for books, tutorials, screencasts and videos, that would be helpfull :) (voted up)

Comment: @Emir: There were not much doc on Struts2 when I used it, but I found very useful the getting started section: http://struts.apache.org/2.2.1.1/docs/home.html

Comment: @Emir: This book http://www.amazon.com/Struts-2-Action-Don-Brown/dp/193398807X is the last one publicised. But I don't know if it good.

Answer (score 0):

My experience with JSF 2.0 has been good and i dont feel any need to learn Spring. From books i can recommend "JavaServer faces 2.0: the complete reference" By Ed Burns, Neil Griffin, Chris Schalk

Comment: I think JSF is similar to the ASP.NET and Spring MVC / Struts II is similar to the ASP.NET MVC

Answer (score 0):

> are there any simmilar technologies like LINQ in java world?

Check out [Scala language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scala_%28programming_language%29). It's full of functional idioms while cooperates with Java pretty smoothly (actually, it's bytecode is the same as Java's. For example, F# requires it's runtime to execute assembly).

And there is awesome [Lift framework](http://www.liftweb.net/lift_overview) supporting MVC pattern among other great features.